# Way to change text color of only a part of a letter in CSS

Tags: html, css

Using CSS, is there a way (hacky or not) to change the color of only *part* of a letter, like [is done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78uNc.png) in the movie Superbad? Ideally, it would be only the parts of a letter that are covering another elment: for example, if I have a red `div` and text partially covering that div, the text would be red if over the body (which is white) and white when over the div.

Comment: Support is not widespread yet, but [`background-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) may allow this. Also note it is "Editor's Draft" status.

Comment: read about blending (some idea : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51630670/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724419/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/51254727/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/49793884/8620333)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character) could be useful

Comment: Yes, [it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372291/javascript-mouse-cursor-circle-effect-with-multiply-background/54372975#54372975).